# Spring Security: User Authorization in Java Class

Tags: java, spring-security

Does Spring Security provide any way to authorize a user in java class, the way it provides tags for authorization in JSPs (such as `<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_ADMIN"/>`)?

I am expecting a static method of some class that I can use in my code like this:

```
if(SomeSpringSecurityClass.authorize("ROLE_ADMIN")){
...
}
```

Comment: If i remember correctly, spring security should provide annotations for this.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better do this check declaratively, but if you still need programmatic way - it has already been discussed on stackoverflow earlier: [How to check "hasRole" in Java Code with Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021200/how-to-check-hasrole-in-java-code-with-spring-security)

In short words, there's no such single ready-made method but you can start from SecurityContextHolder.getContext() to perform this check.