# what's the best way to check user's current authority in spring3 controller methods?

Tags: spring-security, authority

User's authority is frequently changed in my web service.
In this case, how do I check user's authority effectively?

I wrote code that check user's authority in every controller temporarily.
But I think this way would not good for maintenance.

How do I check user's authority without writing checking method in every controller?

Comment: you can also use the nice wrappers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3412166/26510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are doing - Spring Security automatically keeps track of authorities in the User's security context.  If you need to programmatically check for some other reason, then implement the `HandlerInterceptor` interface, and in the preHandle method, call `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to get the current user.  You can then check the User's authorities.

The interceptor would be configured as follows:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.my.package.MyInterceptor" />
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `intercept-url` element to your config with the role that is required, eg.

```
<http auto-config='true'>
  <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_FOO" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [HandlerMethodArgumentResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) to let Spring inject GrantedAuthority in the controller method. If a user can have more than one authority then you will need to create a class to hold user's authorities (can be named as `GrantedAuthorities`). After you are done, your controller method will look something like this:

```
@RequestMapping({"/xyz"})
public String handleXYZRequest(GrantedAuthorities authorities) {
    /* use authorities if not null */
    ...
}
```

In resolver,  you will use the same code that your are currently using to get authorities and it will return either null or `GrantedAuthorities` object. If you are using older version of Spring then use `WebArgumentResolver` and register it with AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.

Above approach avoids duplication of code and it can be used to inject anything you need from `SecurityContextHolder` in controller methods.

**Edit**

This is similar to the approach used by greenhouse. Please see [WebConfig](https://github.com/SpringSource/greenhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springsource/greenhouse/config/WebConfig.java), where principal (which is Account object) is injected in controller through argument resolver.