# Spring security check without submit

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am planning on creating a list of authorized locations for the user to log into if they have more than one, however currently I am not able to do this until the user logs in. The list is grabbed when they authenticate successfully.

I am wondering if anyone knows how to check against a list of roles and count how many a user has.  If there is more than one match in the list I want to return the list in an array.

I am thinking of using hasRole found in [This Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021200/how-to-check-hasrole-in-java-code-with-spring-security) however I am not sure how to compare that against another list, which is stored as xml.

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not understand what you asking: Do you want to have a list of role that a user has (without having them logged in)? - Is that what you asking for?

Comment: @Ralph, Yes that is pretty much what I am looking to do. What I am picturing is using the keyup or blur event to compare their login to the list of logins, if it is valid grabbing their list of access locations.

Comment: Where do you store the user/role relation ship: in a Database, LDAP or Server (in tomcat for example: tomcat-users.xml)?

Comment: The users and their roles are in LDAP.

Comment: Then you need to query the LDAP.

Comment: Ralph, want to add that as a answer so I can give you the rep for it. Turns out that will work for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to get the roles for unauthenticated users, then you need to access the storeage where you store the assignment of users to roles.

If you store the users and roles in an LDAP then you need to query that LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but to get a user's authorities, first call

```
Authentication a  = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

then you can call

```
Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(a.getAuthorities());
```

which will give you the roles as a set of Strings which you can check or count as you please.

Comment: my understanding would be that in order to use getAuthentication() the use would have to enter a password?  I would love to use the username field to get the groups from rather than having to pull from both UN and PW.

Comment: If you're talking about unauthenticated users, then as @Ralph says that depends on how you are storing it.