# How to show a different page for a type of user in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm working in a spring mvc project using spring security, i am new to spring security and i wanted to know how to have two types of users in my application, a normal-user and an admin-user and show a different index page to the admin-user and another index page with less functions to the normal user, so far i have this:

My configSecurity class WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
public class ConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private AutenticarProvider authen;


    @Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception 
    {
        http
            .authenticationProvider(authen)
            .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll() 
                    .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/img/**").permitAll() 
                    .antMatchers("/sound/**").permitAll() 
                    .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/ajax/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/php/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/xml/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") <-- i am not sure about this just guessing
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
            .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/loginPage")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
            .logout()                                    
                    .permitAll();
    }
}
```

And my class that implements AuthenticationProvider:

```
@Component
public class AutenthenProvider implements AuthenticationProvider 
{
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
            throws AuthenticationException {

        User user = null;
        Authentication auth = null;
        String name = null;
        String password = null;

        try 
        {
            name = authentication.getName();
            password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

            if(name != null && !name.trim().equals("") && password != null && !password.trim().equals(""))
            {
                user  =  this.obtainUserFromDataBase(name);

                if(user  != null)
                {
                    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();



                    auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("the user dont exist");

                }

            }
            else
            {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("invalid credentials");
            }
        } 
        catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            throw e;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("", ex.getCause());
        }

        return auth;
    }
```

and my controller method from my controller class

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage(Model model) {

        logger.info("**Login PAGE!!**");

        return "loginPage";
    }
```

I am thinking of putting this line `.antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` in my configure method but i am not sure how this works, if i put that does that mean that i am going to have duplicate pages because there are pages in my application that can be view by both users does this mean that i am going to have those two pages duplicated but in different folders?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tags that Spring has builtin](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/spring-security-part-v-security-tags/) for the purpose based on roles e.g. admin or user. You can also define custom roles.

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">

This content will only be visible to users who have
the "supervisor" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.

</sec:authorize>
```

You might also have luck with the [hasRole([role]) method](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) for a code-based solution or have a look at this answer [How to check "hasRole" in Java Code with Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021200/how-to-check-hasrole-in-java-code-with-spring-security)

Comment: i have a code based configuration and all the tutorials i have found are for xml configuration do you have a code based tutorial perhaps you can give me?

Comment: I think you can use the `hasRole([role])` method (but I didn't try it myself)

Answer (score 0):

First, the correct way is to use roles. In you `AuthenticationProvider`, you give a `GrantedAuthority` `ROLE_ADMIN` to admin users, by slightly modifying it :

```
List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

// only if user is recognized as admin
    grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")

auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password);
```

Then you will be able to use `.antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")` to restrict access to `/admin/**` to admin users, and you can put *in a JSP page*

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">

This content will only be visible to users who have
the "ROLE_ADMIN" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.

</sec:authorize>
```

as proposed by 909 Niklas

Anyway, I almost never had to implement an `AuthenticationProvider`. I generally use a `DaoAuthenticationProvider` and a relevant `UserDetailsService` (`InMemoryUserDetailsManager` for tests and `JdbcUserDetailsManager` when the users are stored in a true database).