# Spring security web check if currently authenticated user has role

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How i can check if currently authenticated user has a specific role?

I found some older solution for older version of spring security, but in current version in spring it's not working, so I'm looking for a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021200/how-to-check-hasrole-in-java-code-with-spring-security) but in `spring-boot-starter-security` version `1.5.2`.

Answer (score 1):

verify if  **authorities**  lenght is >0 :

`Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>)    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities()`;

and after compare with your role if he has roles

Comment: thx for quick reply, i make my own work around, but's it a bit none sense i can do this in thymeleaf : "sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" but not in java codes.

Comment: you'd better also to verify the three level of security ,(1) in your code java ,(2) in (jsp or thymeleaf) , and (3) in xml page accec configuration like `<intercept-url pattern="/downloadWatchPdf" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />`