# Spring Security hasRole() for Unauthenticated Users, Considering Role Hierarchy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a role hierarchy in my Spring Boot 2 + Spring Security application:

```
@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    var rh = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    rh.setHierarchy("ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_USER and ...");

    return rh;
}
```

Now I (as an admin) want to create an entity on behalf of another user, but I should check if that user has a certain authority based on the above hierarchy.

I know that it's possible to [call spring security hasRole()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021200/how-to-check-hasrole-in-java-code-with-spring-security/3100071) for the current authenticated user, but in my case, the user I want to authorize is not authenticated.

Now, I can check to see if the user has that specific authority:

```
public boolean hasAuthority(User user, String authority) {
    return user.getAuthorities()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(grantedAuthority -> grantedAuthority.getName().equals(authority));
}
```

But this way the hierarchy, which is fairly long, would be ignored.

I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the role hierarchy, see [`RoleHierarchy#getReachableGrantedAuthorities`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/hierarchicalroles/RoleHierarchy.html#getReachableGrantedAuthorities-java.util.Collection-):

> ```java
> Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getReachableGrantedAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities)
> ```
>
> Returns an array of all reachable authorities.
>
> Reachable authorities are the directly assigned authorities plus all authorities that are (transitively) reachable from them in the role hierarchy.
>
> Example:
>   Role hierarchy: ROLE_A > ROLE_B and ROLE_B > ROLE_C.
>   Directly assigned authority: ROLE_A.
>   Reachable authorities: ROLE_A, ROLE_B, ROLE_C.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `authorities` - List of the directly assigned authorities.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> List of all reachable authorities given the assigned authorities.

Your modified code:

```java
public boolean hasAuthority(User user, String authority) {
    return roleHierarchy()
        .getReachableGrantedAuthorities(user.getAuthorities())
        .stream()
        .anyMatch(grantedAuthority -> grantedAuthority.getName().equals(authority));
}
```